# CodeIgniter - get current page route

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a page visitor module. The goal is to know the users who visited the most, and what modules the visited the most.

I want to get the page route of the current page.

Here is what I want to do:

1. I have a module called inventory module.
2. This module has a route `'merchandiser/report/inventory'`. (in `routes.php`, it is `$route['merchandiser/report/inventory'])`.

That is the same route that I want to get.

I have tried:

```
<?php echo current_url(); ?>
```

But it returns something like this.

```
192.168.3.3/portal/merchandiser/report/inventory
```

`192.168.3.3/portal/` is my base url`

Now my question is:

How can I remove `192.168.3.3/portal/` and just get `merchandiser/report/inventory`

Hope you can guide me or lead me where to find it.

Thank You.

Comment: `str_replace('192.168.3.3/portal/', '', current_url())` ?

Comment: As @kerbholz said or even more dynamically: `str_replace(base_url(), '', current_url())`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this will help you :

use `url` helper's

```
   uri_string();
```

if your URL was this:

```
http://some-site.com/blog/comments/123
```

The function would return:

```
blog/comments/123
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#uri_string

or you can use uri something like:

```
echo $this->uri->segment(1).'/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/'.$this->uri->segment(3); 

/*produces controller/method/parameter structure
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in codeigniter.

```
$this->uri->segment(1); // controller
$this->uri->segment(2); // action
$this->uri->segment(3); // 1stsegment
$this->uri->segment(4); // 2ndsegment
```

It will return segments of current URL.

Answer (score 2):

in codeigniter 4 you can set route name and use to get route name

```
$router = \CodeIgniter\Config\Services::router();
$current_route = $router->getMatchedRouteOptions()['as'];
```

and to get controller and method

```
$router->controllerName()
$router->methodName();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works like charm:

```
$controller = $this->router->fetch_class();
    $method = $this->router->fetch_method();
    echo $this->uri->uri_string();
```

You can print out the values or redirect after authentication using redirect("$controller/$method");

Answer (score 0):

I think codeigniters urlhelper should do the job with:

```
uri_string(
    current_url()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use this

```
echo base_url(uri_string());
```

Answer (score 0):

I used it like this to get the current page:

```
if (current(array_reverse(explode("/",current_url()))) == 'contato') { }
```